# Why my blender animation broken after exoprt fbx?

Tags: animation, export

in blender the animation
[image: in blender]

in fbx reviewer the animation
[image: in fbx]

[image]

the animation is baked and remove all constraints. but I got wrong result when export fbx.
is blender bug?

My engish is not well. I hope you can understand it. thanks.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but at my experience, FBX doesn't support unequal scale for bones

Comment: I have heard stretch can cause this. There are videos by CGDive on youtube that taught me this, think there is an addon now as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm no expert in Blender at all, but I animated a bit recently and had a similar issue with broken animations when exporting an animated armature.
In particular, the jaw bone of the character jittered around whenever the character moved his head (the jaw bone was an *unconnected* child of the head bone).
In the end, I found no way of preventing this from happening, until I added a new bone connecting the jaw to the head, so the jaw bone is now a *connected* child of the new bone and the new bone is a *connected* child of the head bone.

So connecting the problematic bone(s) to the rest of the mesh seems to fix it and as far as I know, additional bones shouldn't be an issue when set to not-deforming.

I can only explain the initial issue with a bug or something, but I am not sure...
I just hope that this fixes your issue, too.